# M looking for way by which i can show heatpoints on an image according to the data available in database

Tags: javascript, php, heatmap

What i am looking for is ,i have tones of data into my database of various blocks. Now on the basis of range of data i.e if like 5-10(one color),10-20(other color) and so on for all the blocks. Also how m i supposed to add image points on my own image and handle the color of those points according to the range of value using PHP or JS. since i haven't done anything like this before. Any information will be helpful.